# ActiveMQ how to keep message that failed to sent to consumer on queue /topic?

Tags: jms, activemq-classic

I am still learning about this activemq and jms stuff.
I already tried some example and now I can produce and consuming message from the queue/topic.


Now I have a problem, when my client/consumer lost the connection, the message in queue/topic still send out that message, that message become lost and not kept in the queue/topic. So my question is how I can keep that failed message and how to make the broker resend that message again?


thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are mixing up terminology a bit.

Queues will hold messages until consumed or the broker is restarted, unless the message has been marked as persistent, in which case they will stick around even after a broker restart.

Topics only deliver the current message to any current subscriber.  However there are several methods you can use to persist messages published to a topic:

1. Durable subscribers.
2. [Virtual Destinations](http://activemq.apache.org/virtual-destinations.html) .

Virtual Topics tend to be popular for many reasons over durable subscribers, but it really depends on the use-case.

How you create a durable subscriber depends on what you are using to create the subscriber (Spring, POJO, some other API?).  All methods will at some point call the [`Session.createDurableSubscriber`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/jms/Session.html#createDurableSubscriber%28javax.jms.Topic,%20java.lang.String%29) method, but I suggest reading up on  how they behave before choosing this over Virtual Topic or Composite Queues.

Comment: thanks..So, how can I make something like "guaranteed delivery" from broker to the consumer?

Comment: Make sure it is produced as a persistent message.  Additionally, you will want to look at some form of client ack or transactions.

Answer (score 0):

The thing which you are looking for might be `Durable subscription`

You can find documentation for same at http://activemq.apache.org/how-do-durable-queues-and-topics-work.html

Comment: Thanks for your response. How can I set a consumer to be a durable consumer?

Comment: I agree with Erik's answer,you can have a look at that